# How to display "No solution" instead of -1.#IND in do while loop?

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm trying to calculate *y* with *x* going from -1 to 1. If *y* cannot be calculated with current *x* value, it should display "No solution". My code:

```
    void main()
{
double y, t, x = -1; 

do {

    t = sqrt(sin(pow(x, 2))) / (x - 2);
    y = sqrt(2 * t + x);

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "t = " << t << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    cout << endl;

    x++;

} while (x <= 1);

_getch();
```

And this is the output I get:

```
    x = -1
    t = -0.305772
    y= -1.#IND

    x = 0
    t = -0
    y= 0

    x = 1
    t = -0.917317
    y= -1.#IND
```

So if result is `y= -1.#IND` It should display "y = No solution"

Comment: Start looking for what `-1.#IND` means.

Comment: If `(t * 2) + x` is negative, there is no solution - surely you can figure it out?

Comment: Perhaps you should think about why you are getting -1.#IND. If you figure it out, you will see that it is very easy to build the solution you want. Hint: multiplying a real number with itself always produces a positive number.

Comment: I know what's -1.#IND, but instead of it I need the program to display "No solution". I get it because there's a negative number in sqrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- check for a non-negative value before calling `sqrt`
- check whether the result is a number with [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan).

I'd favour the first, since it avoids unnecessary calculations, and works with any floating-point implementation. The second might cause a run-time error, rather than return a "not-a-number" result, on some implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I checked if there's a negative value inside sqrt, and if there was I told it to display "y = no solution". I thought it's gonna be more complex..